# How can I simply make a react component npm package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, package, node-modules

I've been building this react calendar component [see here](https://codepen.io/ryansaam/pen/OweQMm). In the future I'm going to add a whole bunch of features to it and wanted it to be accessible to any developer so I published it on npm. Now I thought you would be able to `npm install <package>` and then add it in any new project. However apparently it's not so easy based on what I've found on google. Everyone else who does this makes a boiler plate with react, react-dom, webpack, babel, and everything else for a standard react application. To me, it seems like this is a bit much just to be able to share a component with others. Is there a way to simply install a react component and add it to your project?

For example say I just made a component I want to share:

```
export const Add = (props) => {
  let sum = props.a + props.b
  return (
    <span>{sum}</span>
  )
}
```

I `npm publish add-component`
Then in a new project `npm create-react-app my-app`
Then `npm install add-component`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import { Add } from 'add-component'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <h1>Welcome to react!</h1>
        <Add a={2} b={2} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

Since `create-react-app` comes with babel and webpack pre-configured and installed shouldn't it be that simple? For some reason it's not. So if anyone is use to this kind of thing could you explain why this doesn't work and what's the bare minimum that you need to export a component and be able to import it from modules?

For more clarity on what I'm publishing on npm see the git repository [here](https://github.com/ryansaam/colorful-calendar)
I'm trying to get it to work like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Calendar from 'Calendar'
import { redflat } from 'calendar.colors'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Calendar
          date={new Date()}
          colors={redflat}
        />
      <div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `export const Add = () => ...`?

Answer (score 0):

Going through all of the steps for a proper npm publish is perhaps beyond the scope of a simple SO answer. The reason most people just use boilerplates is because it can get so involved... however, you are right that the boilerplates contain a lot of cruft that can be avoided.

The bare basics of what you will need are here: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages.

You should also review https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/packages as you will need to have a single file somewhere (either `index.js` or something pointed to by the `main` field in `package.json`) that exports the code that you want to make available.

Finally, you should make sure that you test your module works (specifically, that all of your dependencies are properly accounted for) before publishing. There are a variety of ways to do this, but I'd recommend having some test scripts that you can run, deleting and reinstalling `node_modules`, and running the test scripts.

Bonus: Make sure you have a `.npmignore` to avoid publishing unnecessary files.

Comment: I'm familiar on how to make a npm package. I've already published it on npm [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/colorful-calendar). I just don't know why when I import it in react from node_modules it doesn't work the same as if I were to make a component in my react application and import it from my src directory. I think it has something to do with webpack but I can't find anything in the react docs explaining it.

Comment: In your Githhub, you have a package.json with a main field pointing to a nonexistent Calendar.js file. Thus, the dependency resolution wont work. See my note and link about modules above.